# To rewrite a javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not a sharp jquery / javascript coder yet - so I hope that there is a kind soul out there, who can help me with rewriting a javascript into a jQuery script.

The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function update_delivery_address()
{
    elm_true = document.getElementById('delivery_same_as_invoice_true');
    elm_false = document.getElementById('delivery_same_as_invoice_false');
    if (!elm_true.checked && !elm_false.checked)
    {
        elm_true.checked = true;
    }
    if (elm_true.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('delivery_name').value = '';
        document.getElementById('delivery_att').value = '';
        document.getElementById('delivery_address').value = '';
        document.getElementById('delivery_zipcode').value = '';
        document.getElementById('delivery_city').value = '';
        document.getElementById('delivery_email').value = '';
        document.getElementById('delivery_name').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('delivery_att').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('delivery_address').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('delivery_zipcode').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('delivery_city').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('delivery_email').disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('delivery_name').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('delivery_att').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('delivery_address').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('delivery_zipcode').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('delivery_city').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('delivery_email').disabled = false;
    }
}

update_delivery_address();
</script>
```

Comment: Learn $(selector), $().val(), $().attr() functions yourself. I don't think so anyone on Stackoverflow will write the entire jquery script for you. Just learn those 3 things and your requirement would be served.

Comment: I know that Stack Overflow isn't a code translation service - I'm just under a little timepressure, and hoped that there was a kind soul out there. And the script isn't that difficult - so a good programmer could easily do this in 2 mins. And I would like to learn how to code my own jQuery scripts, but I just don't have the time at the moment to sit down and  read about jQuery / javascript... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily done. Replace all

```
document.getElementById('yourid')
```

with

```
$('#yourid')
```

Replace all

```
.value = ''
```

with

```
.val('')
```

Replace all

```
.disabled = true (or false)
```

with

```
.prop('disabled', true) // or false
```

Replace all

```
.checked = true (or false)
```

with

```
.prop('checked', true) // or false
```

and all

```
.checked
```

with

```
.prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would assign all of the input fields a class (like .delivery or something) so that selection is way easier, and you could select by class:

```
$('.delivery')
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for more on that.

And then set all of your attributes accordingly

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is used to get things done in less time. For example you can write

`elm_true = $('#delivery_same_as_invoice_true').get(0);`

instead of

`elm_true = document.getElementById('delivery_same_as_invoice_true');`

Nevertheless the code still remains (valid) JavaScript - there is no need to rewrite your code (except of the readability).

If you want to rewrite your code anyway you can replace the

`var_name = document.getElementById('someid');`

lines by

`var_name = $('#someid').get(0);`

and

`document.getElementById('someid').attribute = value`

by

`$('#someid').attr("attribute",value)`

for example

`$('#delivery_name').attr('disabled',false);`

Comment: `$('#delivery_same_as_invoice_true')` is **not** the same thing as `document.getElementById('delivery_same_as_invoice_true')`.

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL you are right, thanks - I just corrected it

Comment: You've rather missed the point. Using jQuery for selectors and then `.get(0)`ing? Sure, now you've written exactly equivalent code, but lost the benefit of the rest of the jQuery API.

Comment: He wants the jQuery equivalent of his code - and that is just what I wrote. I know there is no sense doing it that way, but that's just what he asked for.